# Sum the Days in a System Status By Calculating the Difference in Days from each set of entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am subtracting the days between respective dates that an item is in a system status. The formula I am using works when there are only 2 entries, but often there are 3 or more. Meaning an input into the status and update out of the status and a consecutive update back in the status and so forth. All of which have a respective Stat code which will be the same for any respective status and incrementally greater change numbers (001,002,003,...). Each of which are differing dates. How can I calculate the difference in days between instance 002 and 001 and then sum that to the difference in 004 - 003.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) as COUNT, 
    JCDS_SOGR.OBJNR, 
    JCDS_SOGR.STAT, 
    TJ30T.TXT30, 
    DIF = CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(JCDS_SOGR.UDATE),MAX(JCDS_SOGR.UDATE))
        WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(JCDS_SOGR.UDATE),GETDATE())
    END
FROM
    JCDS_SOGR
    JOIN TJ30T 
        ON JCDS_SOGR.STAT = TJ30T.ESTAT
WHERE
    JCDS_SOGR.OBJNR = 'IE000000000010003137'
    AND TJ30T.SPRAS='E'
    AND TJ30T.MANDT='400'
    AND STSMA = 'VEHICLE'
GROUP BY
    JCDS_SOGR.OBJNR,
    JCDS_SOGR.STAT, 
    TJ30T.TXT30
```

Actual Results
Sum Difference in Days Of Different Sets of Dates

This is [a Sample of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFMip.png) for One Status and Object that has 7 entries:

```
MANDT   OBJNR              STAT    CHGNR UDATE    INACT CHIND
IE000000000010003137    E0004   001 20110815        I 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   002 20130605    X   U 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   003 20130913        U 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   004 20150323    X   U 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   005 20150512        U 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   006 20151125    X   U 400
IE000000000010003137    E0004   007 20160927        U 400
```

This is [the Result from My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikMlk.png) Max (20160927) - Min (20110815):

```
COUNT    OBJNR              STAT    TXT30       DIF
7   IE000000000010003137    E0004   Operational 1870
```

Expected Results ((002 -001) + (004-003)+ (006-005)+ (getdate() -007)):

This is [What the Result in the Dif Column Should Be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u1pH.png):

```
COUNT    OBJNR              STAT    TXT30       DIF
7   IE000000000010003137    E0004   Operational 2253
```

Comment: I'm confused.  You show a sample of data as a single table, but you have a query with two tables.

Comment: Gordon, it’s a sample of the entries. All 7 of the sample entries are the same STAT code thus it will be grouped together based on the group by direction at the bottom of the code. Resulting in one line. Does that help?

Comment: The 2nd table in query is pulling the TXT30 field so I know the definition of the STAT code “Operational”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query.

```
    ;with cte
    AS
    (
        Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by STAT Order by UDATE ) as Rn,  
        *,
        LAG(UDATE) OVER(partition by STAT Order by UDATE ) As PrevUDate,
        COUNT(*) OVER(partition by STAT) As [Count]
        from YourTable
    )



    Select Max(rn) As [Count],
    OBJNR,STAT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rn%2=0 THEN DATEDIFF(d,PrevUDate,UDATE) 
            WHEN rn=[Count] THEN  DATEDIFF(d,UDATE,getDate())   
        ELSE 0 END)
    from cte
    Group BY OBJNR, STAT
```

Comment: Hi Sahi, I cast the vote but because I am new to stack overflow my response is not  displayed only recorded. It will display once I have 15 badge points.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Erikah. It should give you enough to get you in the right direction. You can run the following T-SQL in SSMS.

I created a *table variable* based on your initial dataset ( This is a Sample of Data for One Status and Object that has 7 entries ) in lieu of fetching the actual data as I don't have access to it, obviously. I also made assumptions with the data types for this example.

```
-- Create table variable for the data --
DECLARE @data TABLE (
    MANDT VARCHAR(50)
    , OBJNR VARCHAR(50)
    , STAT VARCHAR(50)
    , CHGNR VARCHAR(3)
    , UDATE DATETIME
    , INACT VARCHAR(1)
    , CHIND VARCHAR(1)
);

-- Add the sample data --
INSERT INTO @data (
    MANDT, OBJNR, STAT, CHGNR, UDATE, INACT, CHIND
) VALUES
  ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '001', '20110815', '', 'I' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '002', '20130605', 'X', 'U' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '003', '20130913', '', 'U' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '004', '20150323', 'X', 'U' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '005', '20150512', '', 'U' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '006', '20151125', 'X', 'U' )
, ( '400', 'IE000000000010003137', 'E0004', '007', '20160927', '', 'U' );
```

Table variable @data contains:

```
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
| MANDT |        OBJNR         | STAT  | CHGNR |          UDATE          | INACT | CHIND |
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   001 | 2011-08-15 00:00:00.000 |       | I     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   002 | 2013-06-05 00:00:00.000 | X     | U     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   003 | 2013-09-13 00:00:00.000 |       | U     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   004 | 2015-03-23 00:00:00.000 | X     | U     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   005 | 2015-05-12 00:00:00.000 |       | U     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   006 | 2015-11-25 00:00:00.000 | X     | U     |
|   400 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |   007 | 2016-09-27 00:00:00.000 |       | U     |
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------+-------------------------+-------+-------+
```

Next, I queried the data using SQL Server's LEAD and LAG functions ( in the derived table ) to look at the previous or following UDATE values to calculate a DATEDIFF.

```
-- Query for the desired resultset --
SELECT
    COUNT ( * ) AS [COUNT]
    , obj.OBJNR
    , obj.STAT
    , ( 'Operational' ) AS TXT30
    , SUM( obj.dif ) AS DIF
FROM (

    -- Query a DATEDIFF resultset --
    SELECT
        OBJNR
        , STAT
        , CASE INACT
            -- If the current record's INACT = X get the date difference between this and the PREVIOUS record using LAG.
            WHEN 'X' THEN DATEDIFF( DD, LAG( UDATE, 1, 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY CHGNR ), UDATE )
            -- Otherwise, check if we are at the end of the resultset using LEAD...
            ELSE CASE LEAD( INACT, 1, '' ) OVER ( ORDER BY CHGNR )
                WHEN '' THEN DATEDIFF( DD, UDATE, GETDATE() )
                ELSE 0
            END
        END AS dif
    FROM @data

) AS obj
GROUP BY
    obj.OBJNR, obj.STAT;
```

Query resultset:

```
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------------+------+
| COUNT |        OBJNR         | STAT  |    TXT30    | DIF  |
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------------+------+
|     7 | IE000000000010003137 | E0004 | Operational | 2253 |
+-------+----------------------+-------+-------------+------+
```

Note my use of LEAD and LAG. In the case of LEAD here, I am looking if there is another record. If there isn't one, in this case noted by LEAD returning an empty string, then we've reached the end of the dataset.

LEAD's third parameter is the value to return in the event no data exists for the specified condition. In this case I return and empty string, at which point the DATEDIFF is calculated off the current date using GETDATE() as there is no other record to compare it to.

If you were to look at the resultset for the derived table's query you would see:

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+-----+
|        OBJNR         | STAT  | INACT | dif |
+----------------------+-------+-------+-----+
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |       |   0 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 | X     | 660 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |       |   0 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 | X     | 556 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |       |   0 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 | X     | 197 |
| IE000000000010003137 | E0004 |       | 840 |
+----------------------+-------+-------+-----+
```

The outer SELECT simply SUMs the values of [dif].

I hope this helps.

P.S. You can read more about LAG: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and LEAD: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This is a good answer.  I had to tweak the syntax of the case statements, but otherwise this is how SQL should solve this question.

Comment: Wow Critical Error you are marvelous. Thank you so much! :) This made my day. I have been going at this for weeks.

Comment: Thank you for the notes as well, they are so helpful!